# BUILD ERROR in NPM release step AzureDevOps: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin

Tags: npm, azure-devops

We are encountering following issue in the Build step of NPM release.

We tried hardcoding the npm version from earlier successful release but it didn't work.

```
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
 at Processor.normalize (D:\agent1\_work\r71\a\swagger-codegen\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:145:15)
 at new Processor (D:\agent1\_work\r71\a\swagger-codegen\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:51:25)
 at postcss (D:\agent1\_work\r71\a\swagger-codegen\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:73:10)
 at createPostCssProcessor (D:\agent1\_work\r71\a\swagger-codegen\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:73:12)
 at Object.<anonymous> (D:\agent1\_work\r71\a\swagger-codegen\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:36:30)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your issue? Please add your pipeline and detailed log, and how you hardcoding the npm version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update npm version in your pipeline, you could try to use the Npm Version command. For example:

[image]

Comment: Is my reply helpful?